# Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'screendata'

Tags: ios, game-center, undeclared-identifier

I've been using [buzztouch.com](http://buzztouch.com) to create an app and have no coding experience. I've been trying to integrate Game Center into my app through Xcode. I've been following [these instructions](http://buzztouch.com/resources/Game-Center-Tutorial.pdf) and copying and pasting code where instructed. When I tried running the app through the simulator, I got the error that said:

Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'screendata'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying and pasting the code, you need to understand it. 
Something wasn't copied quite right, or maybe there is a typo in the code that you copied.

Anyway, your code refers to an identifier "screendata" and the compiler has no idea what screendata is. Could be just misspelled. Best is to *understand* the code so that you could write it yourself, and then you can figure out how to fix it.